# babel.config.js: Error while loading config - Cannot find module 'fibers'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, babeljs, vuetify.js

This is driving me nuts.

IDE: Visual Studion 2019
Project: Created a new "Basic Vue.js project" - I chose the *.ts flavour

I validate the new site runs. It does.

Following the quick start on Vuetify : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object

After each step I validate the site will still compile and run.

I reach the section where we add new modules to our project. I run this line:

```
npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
```

And now the site will not run. When I debug I get this output:

```
------ Build started: Project: MCCC.Web, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        > mccc.web@0.1.0 build C:\Labs\MCCC\Web\MCCC-Web\MCCC.Web
        > vue-cli-service build
        -  Building for production...
        Starting type checking service...
        Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
         ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors5:04:50 PM
         error  in ./src/main.ts
        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
        Thread Loader (Worker 0)
        C:\Labs\MCCC\Web\MCCC-Web\MCCC.Web\babel.config.js: Error while loading config - Cannot find module 'fibers'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
            at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
            at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
            at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Labs\MCCC\Web\MCCC-Web\MCCC.Web\babel.config.js:17:32)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
         @ multi ./src/main.ts
         ERROR  Build failed with errors.
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! mccc.web@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR! 
        npm ERR! Failed at the mccc.web@0.1.0 build script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dwainwright.BC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-26T21_04_50_521Z-debug.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets(60,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
Done building project "MCCC.Web.njsproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The line that sticks out the most to me is:

```
C:\Labs\MCCC\Web\MCCC-Web\MCCC.Web\babel.config.js: Error while loading config - Cannot find module 'fibers'
```

fibres is references in the babel.config.json where I added the rules laid out in quick start:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
        '@vue/app',
        '@babel/preset-env'
    ],
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
            use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
                    options: {
                    implementation: require('sass'),
                    fiber: require('fibers'),
                    indentedSyntax: true // optional
                },
                // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
                options: {
                    implementation: require('sass'),
                    sassOptions: {
                        fiber: require('fibers'),
                        indentedSyntax: true // optional
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
]
};
```

Does anybody know how i can resolve this? Happy to share further info; not sure what else you may need.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of the docs? I followed the link you provided and the anchor `#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object` doesn't appear to exist anymore. I was able to get a basic project up and running successfully following these steps:

1. `vue create myapp`: Selected "custom" and ticked all the boxes, for TypeScript, chose the default "class-style components"
2. verified that `npm run serve` worked
3. `vue add vuetify`: Selected "Configure", and these options:

   1. Y (default)
   2. y
   3. y
   4. Material Design Icons (default)
   5. N (default)
   6. Y (default)
   7. English (default)
4. `npm run serve` would run, but I got warnings about type declaration for `vuetify/lib`. [This answer](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5944#issuecomment-613062365) led me to [this FAQ item](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/frequently-asked-questions/#when-adding-typescript-error-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-vuetify-lib) which made the warnings go away. (You have to add `"vuetify"` to the `compilerOptions.types` array in the root `tsconfig.json` for the project.)

FWIW, `fibers` does not appear to be included in the project at all anymore (searched for "fibers" in `package-lock.json`). My `babel.config.js` file looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

And `vue.config.js` looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!